# how to configure boot2docker kernel compilation to include snd_aloop support?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot2docker

I need to run docker containers that depend on `snd_aloop` module. I have [read](http://dummdida.tumblr.com/post/117157045170/modprobe-in-a-docker-container) that the module can be loaded inside the containers with `modprobe` if they are run in privileged mode.

In this context, I understand that the module needs to be available on the host.

I develop on MacOSX. Which implies running containers in `boot2docker`.  As far as I can see, `boot2docker` does not come with `snd_aloop` module: I do not find `kernel/sound/drivers/snd-aloop.ko` in `/lib/modules`.

`docker-machine` makes it easy to [use a custom](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/) `boot2docker` image. I have followed `boot2docker` [build instructions](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#making-your-own-customised-boot2docker-iso).

The `boot2docker` build process uses [`kernel_config`](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/kernel_config) as a base for kernel compilation configuration `make oldconfig`. 
I have tried to add the following options in `kernel_config`:

```
CONFIG_SND=m
CONFIG_SND_ALOOP=m
```

before running `make oldconfig`. But without any success. The generated `.config` does not keep any pointers to `CONFIG_SND*`. And thus obviously does not compile support for `snd_aloop`.

What am I misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jean-François Roche](https://twitter.com/jf_roche) hinted me: I figured out what is below.

Instead of guessing configuration like

```
CONFIG_SND=m
```

I should have run `make defconfig`.

Then check `.config` and find which config might be needed.

I finally succeeded with, among others

```
CONFIG_SOUND=y
CONFIG_SOUND_OSS_CORE=y
CONFIG_SOUND_OSS_CORE_PRECLAIM=y
CONFIG_SND=y
CONFIG_SND_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_SND_ALOOP=m
```